# Closing old or self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Is there a protocol for closing old or self-answered questions? When you walk through many of the unanswered questions there are some that have been resolved without an answer ever being provided. For example: [Categories Tag inside of Channel Entries Tag understanding problem](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9379/categories-tag-inside-of-channel-entries-tag-understanding-problem)

Is there a way community members or moderators can close some of these?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the questions the OP actually found a solution and it's just in the comments or they updated the original question. In those cases, we should encourage the poster to add an answer with the details so others can easily find it in future. Alternatively, feel free to just post your answer stating that per the comments the solution was (...) etc.

For questions where the poster has clearly abandoned SE and doesn't look like they will be coming back to answer it any time soon (e.g. if someone asked for more info, and the OP never replied), we can close as "Not a Real Question". Once you have 500 rep you will be able to cast close votes on questions (it takes 5 votes or 1 moderator to close a question). Until then, feel free to "flag" the questions and a moderator can close them if necessary.